# Pass variable to PHP with JS

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have an HTML form which i populate from a database. On submit we load a page called "viewgame.php". Now what i want is here to run some scripts to populate some tables with data but how exactly can i pass the variable which i got from the form ex.  `$_POST['gameNo']` to the other php file though JavaScript?

Below is some of my code
JS function

```
function refreshGameinfo() {
    var load = $.get('gameinfo_sc.php');
    $(".gameinfo").html('Refreshing');
    load.error(function() {
        console.log("Mlkia kaneis");
        $(".gameinfo").html('failed to load');
        // do something here if request failed
    });
    load.success(function(res) {
        console.log("Success");
        $(".gameinfo").html(res);
    });
    load.done(function() {
        console.log("Completed");
    });
}
```

How can i pass the `$POST_['gameNo']` to the `gameinfo_sc.php` file so that i can get the correct results?

Comment: Use $_GET in your php file

Comment: Or save the data into a $_SESSION.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
var load = $.get('gameinfo_sc.php',{gameNo:"1212"});
```

In your php file you can access it using

```
$_GET['gameNo']
```

For post method use

```
var load = $.post('gameinfo_sc.php',{gameNo:"1212"});
```

In your php file you can access it using

```
$_POST['gameNo']
```

Comment: thanks worked great,
`var load = $.get('gameinfo_sc.php',{gameNo:"<?php echo $_POST['gameNo']; ?>"});` and used $_GET['gameNo'] to get it.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to post `$POST_['gameNo']` to `gameinfo_sc.php` but `$.get` isn't the right method for post, its actually for `http get`. you can also do this by using `$.post` http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

```
function refreshGameinfo() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "gameinfo_sc.php",
            data: {gameNo: data},
            cache: false,
            success: function(html){
                console.log( "Success" );
                $(".gameinfo").html(res);
            },
            error:function(html){
                console.log("Mlkia kaneis");
                $(".gameinfo").html('failed to load');
            }
        });
    }
```

try this

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

(in html layout):

```
<input type="hidden" id="gameNo" value="<?=$_POST['gameNo']?>" />
```

(in js file):

```
var gameNo = $('#gameNo').val();
var load = $.get('gameinfo_sc.php', {gameNo: gameNo});
....
```

**UPDATE:**

If your server doesn't support [short open tags](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag), you can write:

```
<input type="hidden" id="gameNo" value="<?php echo $_POST['gameNo'] ?>" />
```